# How may I project vectors onto a plane defined by its orthogonal vector in Python?

Tags: python, math, 3d, linear-algebra

I have a plane, `plane A`, defined by its orthogonal vector, say `(a, b, c)`.

(i.e. the vector `(a, b, c)` is orthogonal to `plane A`)

I wish to project a vector `(d, e, f)` onto `plane A`.

**How can I do it in Python?** I think there must be some easy ways.

Comment: this is not a python problem; this is a regular math problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take `(d, e, f)` and subtract off the projection of it onto the normalized normal to the plane (in your case `(a, b, c)`). So:

```
v = (d, e, f)
        - sum((d, e, f) *. (a, b, c)) * (a, b, c) / sum((a, b, c) *. (a, b, c))
```

Here, by `*.` I mean the *component-wise* product. So this would mean:

```
sum([x * y for x, y in zip([d, e, f], [a, b, c])])
```

or

```
d * a + e * b + f * c
```

if you just want to be clear but pedantic

and similarly for `(a, b, c) *. (a, b, c)`. Thus, in Python:

```
from math import sqrt

def dot_product(x, y):
    return sum([x[i] * y[i] for i in range(len(x))])

def norm(x):
    return sqrt(dot_product(x, x))

def normalize(x):
    return [x[i] / norm(x) for i in range(len(x))]

def project_onto_plane(x, n):
    d = dot_product(x, n) / norm(n)
    p = [d * normalize(n)[i] for i in range(len(n))]
    return [x[i] - p[i] for i in range(len(x))]
```

Then you can say:

```
p = project_onto_plane([3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: *. seems not to be identified by the compiler: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Why?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: Because it's *not* Python. I spelled out for you how to translate `*.` to Python.

Comment: oh, I see. I am such a newbie in Python. Could you please show me the code? I know hoe to do it in maths. What I don't know and therefore am asking is how to do it in Python codes..

Comment: thanks for the codes! but for the `norm()`, shouldn't it be `sqrt(dot_product(x, x))` instead of `dot_product(x, x)`?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: Yes, sorry.

Comment: also, by maths, should be `p = [d / norm(n) * normalize(n)[i] for i in range(len(n))]`. Please check and if I am right, please kindly modify the answer. :)