# how to intersect two planes in python and export the coordinates of the intersection

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, geometry, plane

I have a bunch of points (`x`, `y` and `z`) in a 3d space and want to extract some points out of them. I copied a simplified example with two arrays which are linked together:

```
all_points=[[np.array([[6.8,1.,0.1], [6.8,3.,0.1], [6.8,6.,0.1],\
                       [4.8,1.,2.], [4.8,3.,2.], [4.8,6.,2.],\
                       [3.8,1.,3.], [3.8,3.,3.], [3.8,6.,3.],\
                       [2.8,1.,4.1], [2.8,3.,4.1], [2.8,6.,4.1]]),\
             np.array([[5.,1.,2.], [5.,3.,2.], [5.,6.,2.],\
                       [4.,1.,3.], [4.,3.,3.], [4.,6.,3.],\
                       [6.,1.,3.], [6.,3.,3.], [6.,6.,3.],\
                       [7.,1.,4.], [7.,3.,4.], [7.,6.,4.],\
                       [3.,1.,4.], [3.,3.,4.], [3.,6.,4.]])]]
```

Firstly, I want to check whether the array is normal or not. If I sort a normal array based on `z` values, the `x` value of srted array will be increasing or decreasing. First array (blue dots in upladed fig) clearly show a normal set. For normal arrays I just do a simple task and export four points showing  corners of them (shown by yellow and green arrows in my fig). These points are found based on the minimum and maximum of `x`, `y` and `z`. Following code gives me four corners of normals:

```
four_corners=[]
for points in all_points:
    for sub_points in points:
        sorted_sub=np.sort(sub_points.view('i8,i8,i8'), order=['f2', 'f1'], axis=0).view('float')
        le_st=sorted_sub[np.where(sorted_sub[:,2] == sorted_sub[0,2])]
        le_st=len(le_st)
        le_en=sorted_sub[np.where(sorted_sub[:,2] == sorted_sub[-1,2])]
        le_en=len(le_en)
        cor=np.array([sorted_sub[0,:], sorted_sub[int((le_st-1)),:], sorted_sub[-1,:], sorted_sub[-le_en,:]])
        four_corners.append(cor)
```

In abnormal sets (black squares in my fig) usually some points  are very close to a normal set (a limit can be defined) and then they go away. I want to extract four points but by creating two planes. First plane is created using three of the four corners points found for the normal points. Second surface is created using each three points of the abnormal points that are not close to the normal points (highlighted by a red line in my fig). Then, I want to find intersection line of two surfaces and find the `x` and `z` in the minimum and maximum of `y` (`1` and `6`) of the intersection. `y` value of all my corners points (normal or abnormal) is the minimum or maximum value. Other two points are created by substituting the `y` and `z` values of the two corners points coming from the normal plane that have higher `z` values (highlted by yellow arrows) into the equation of the plane of abnormal set. I only know how to create surfaces based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818203/how-to-find-the-coordinate-of-points-projection-on-a-planar-surface/64835893#64835893). In reality I may have several normal and abnormal sets that all are linked to the normal. In advance, I do appreciate any help and contribution for doing what I want in python.

[image]

Comment: I think you better do [plane fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plane+fitting()) on each of your sets. Then the intersection of those two planes is a 3D straight. Last  part is finding points that are in (or close enough to) the straight.

Comment: Dear @Ripi2, Thanks for your attention. I just want corners of two surfaces. For normal ones everything is okay but the abnormal one is alongside the normal one in some locations and then it goes away. I only want to use the points that are far from the normal one because they really represent the abnormal plane.